# Access specific instances in list in dataframe column, and also count list length - R

Tags: r

I have an R dataframe composed of columns. One column contains lists: i.e.

```
      Column
      1,2,4,7,9,0
      5,3,8,9,0
      3,4
      5.8,9,3.5
      6
      NA
      7,4,3
```

I would like to create column which counts, the length of these lists:

```
Column            Count
1,2,4,7,9,0       6
5,3,8,9,0         5
3,4               2
5.8,9,3.5        3
6                1
NA               NA
7,4,3            3
```

Also, is there a way to access specific instances in these lists? i.e. make a new column with only the first instances of each list? or the last instances of each?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use `strsplit` to split element in character vector and use `sapply` to get the desired count:

```
df$count <- sapply(strsplit(df$Column, ","),function(x){
  if(all(is.na(x))){
    NA
  } else {
    length(x)
  }
})
df
# Column          count
# 1 1,2,4,7,9,0     6
# 2   5,3,8,9,0     5
# 3         3,4     2
# 4   5.8,9,3.5     3
# 5           6     1
# 6        <NA>    NA
# 7       7,4,3     3
```

If it is desired to count `NA` as `1` then solution could have been even simpler as:

```
df$count <- sapply(strsplit(df$Column, ","),length)
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = "Column
'1,2,4,7,9,0'
'5,3,8,9,0'
'3,4'
'5.8,9,3.5'
'6'
NA
'7,4,3'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This worked , thank you ! would you know anything about accessing specific instances within the lists? i.e. making a column out of all of the last instances?

Comment: `lengths` is a quicker and direct version of `sapply(x, length)` - `lengths(strsplit(df$Column, ","))` for instance.

Comment: A similar method using `sum`, `is.na`, and everyone's favorite NA exponentiation is `sapply(strsplit(df$Column, split=","), function(x) sum(!is.na(x))) * NA^is.na(df$Column)`.

Answer (score 2):

`count.fields` serves this purpose for a text file, and can be coerced to work with a column too:

```
df$Count <- count.fields(textConnection(df$Column), sep=",")
df$Count[is.na(df$Column)] <- NA

df
#       Column Count
#1 1,2,4,7,9,0     6
#2   5,3,8,9,0     5
#3         3,4     2
#4   5.8,9,3.5     3
#5           6     1
#6        <NA>    NA
#7       7,4,3     3
```

On a more general note, you're probably better off converting your column to a list, or stacking the data to a long form, to make it easier to work with:

```
df$Column <- strsplit(df$Column, ",")
lengths(df$Column)
#[1] 6 5 2 3 1 1 3
sapply(df$Column, `[`, 1)
#[1] "1"   "5"   "3"   "5.8" "6"   NA    "7"  

stack(setNames(df$Column, seq_along(df$Column)))
#   values ind
#1       1   1
#2       2   1
#3       4   1
#4       7   1
#5       9   1
#6       0   1
#7       5   2
#8       3   2
#9       8   2
# etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly faster way to achieve the same result:

```
df$Count <- nchar(gsub('[^,]', '', df$Column)) + 1
```

This one works by counting how many commas there are and adding 1.